# selecting BIT field in sub query gives '49' instead of 0 or 1

Tags: mysql

```
select *, (select logactivity from users where regtoken= '12345') as log from server
```

the log activity field in 'users' is a BIT field which under "SELECT * FROM USERS" comes up 0 or 1. But when I use the subquery above, I get 49 instead of 1, 48 instead of 0. Why?

Comment: Any sample data set with your table definitions ?

Answer (score 1):

48 and 49 are integer values of character (ascii) representations of characters`0` and `1` .
Perhaps the issue is not in your query, but in your code somewhere which deals with this case.

*php example* : http://codepad.org/5i65IWTG

Comment: I'm typing the query into Workbench. How do I change it?

Comment: [here you go?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a556/1)  It dosen't happen here. Only on my server.

Comment: Can you post "show create table MY_TABLE" of logactivity and other tables. I suspect you might be using a char/varchar field to store boolean data.

Comment: I'm not. 
  [`logactivity` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1'] it's happening with any subquery  to a field with bit value, but not when I join tables.